# How to send one notification on all days except Sunday in Cordova for Android?

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I'm looking to notify the user to update their info every day except on Sundays. How would I do this using Cordova? I looked into LocalNotification, but it doesn't provide an option to send only on specific days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could schedule multiple weekly notifications (adapted from [sample](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/11.-Samples)):

```
days = [saturday_at_8am,sunday_at_8am];
for(i=0;i<days.length;i++){
    timing = days[i]
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: i,
        text: "Good morning!",
        firstAt: timing,
        every: "week"
    });
);
```

The above should schedule local notifications every Saturday & Sunday at 8am.

Comment: Thanks, will try this. Also, do you have any idea if clicking the notifications will directly open the app, or do I need to add an event listener?

Comment: It should open the app.

Comment: And how do I need to write this script?
Do I need to run cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule() just once when the user sets up their settings, or every time the app is opened (in the index.html file or an externally linked JS file)?

Comment: Just once should do on first run

Comment: And if I implement it in the index.html, apart from the tiny performance issues, will I face any problem? Multiple notifications or something? Because I'm going to update the app and the users have already set things up. :/

Comment: I can't really answer this without looking at your specific implementation. Whatever it is, to prevent any accidental mess-ups you should definitely run appropriate tests.